# packer - ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, hashsum, checksum, pgp

I'm trying to install `ncurses5-compat-libs` on Arch Linux with `packer`.

But I get this error:

> ==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

You should stick to a manual installation using `makepkg` and understand how the compilation and installation process from the AUR works before using an AUR helper.

Anyway, you have to import the PGP signature of the package before you install it. You can install the package without verifying its PGP signature but you shouldn't do it. You can import the PGP signature of `ncurses5-compat-libs` by using this command:

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys F7E48EDB
```

Read the `makepkg` man page and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg) article before installing another package from the AUR.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend the answer a bit.

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
datamash-1.1.1.tar.gz ... FAILED (unknown public key 0A11B61D3657B901)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build datamash.
```

Yes you need to add the key. 
That won't work until you have created your own gpg key.
You only need to generate your own key once.

```
gpg --full-gen-key
```

Then you can import the key that is holding up the build process.

```
gpg --recv-key 0A11B61D3657B901
gpg --lsign 0A11B61D3657B901
```

If you want to understand what is going on here is some reading
http://allanmcrae.com/2015/01/two-pgp-keyrings-for-package-management-in-arch-linux/

as well as the arch wiki.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG

Answer (score 0):

### **Option 1** (recommended)

It is also **important** to keep the **`archlinux-keyring`-package** and the system **up-to-date** - especially 
the `archlinux-keyring`-package.

A not up-to-date `archlinux-keyring`-package can cause PGP signatures to be missing and thus problems with the PGP signatures.

--

### **Option 2 (*not* recommended)**

As a [quick and dirty fix](http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?pid=20748#p20748) *this* was proposed on the archbang forum:

> **Warning:** Following these instructions chould damage yours and others system with dangerous malware!
>
>  Installation ***without (!)*** integrity check: `packer -S --skipinteg <package>`